# How to properly setup the Airbnb's javascript linter in Atom?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, lint, eslint

Surprisingly, there is not any good guide on this. 
I cannot make the linter work. I have set the .eslintrc that extends airbnb on the directory where I save all my projects. I do not know if it is the right directory. I also did [this](https://gist.github.com/darokel/90fe5c8ad8df5efcab6b). Nothing is being lint in Atom (the file does have linting errors), so I guess there are some missing steps.

Comment: To the close-voter: how is this off-topic? It *specifically* states in the help center that questions about programming-related tools are *on topic*. To quote: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they *directly involve tools used primarily for programming*" (emphasis mine). It may have other issues, but relevance to SO is not one of them.

Comment: Did you manually run the linter using the control palette?

Comment: I haven't done this, but the owner of the Atom-Linter org set it up on a project I maintain. He did it as an extension of the `linter-eslint` package. Check this for more details: https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-puppet-lint/blob/master/package.json

Comment: I'm trying to get out of the question ban. Can somebody explain me why this question has downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [this](http://www.acuriousanimal.com/2016/08/14/configuring-atom-with-eslint.html) guide. It works fine now.

Relevant info from the link:

**Configuring ESLint in your project**

The first thing we need to do is configure ESLint in our project. Remember we are going to use the AirBnB style guide so we need no install the required package and make our ESLint configuration extend from the AirBnB ESLint configuration.

Install ESLint locally to your project: `> npm install eslint --save-dev`.
Install the AirBnB ESLint configuration. Following package instructions we need to execute next sentences to install the right package versions and dependencies:

```
> export PKG=eslint-config-airbnb;
> npm info "$PKG" peerDependencies --json | command sed 's/[\{\},]//g ; s/: /@/g' | xargs npm install --save-dev "$PKG"
```

Create a `.eslintrc` file in the root of our project. We must be sure to include the property `"extends": "airbnb"` as part of the configuration.
Next is a sample configuration file. Note we inherited configuration from AirBnB. In addition, we have added the eslint rules `valid-jsdoc` and `require-jsdoc` to forces us to write some JSDoc for functions, methods and classes.

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true,
    "mocha": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "valid-jsdoc": ["error", {
      "requireReturn": true,
      "requireReturnType": true,
      "requireParamDescription": true,
      "requireReturnDescription": true
    }],
    "require-jsdoc": ["error", {
        "require": {
            "FunctionDeclaration": true,
            "MethodDefinition": true,
            "ClassDeclaration": true
        }
    }]
  }
}
```

Right now our project is configured with ESLint and the base set of rules from AirBnB, but it requires we execute ESLint manually or automatize in some way (in the build process).

**Installing Atom plugins**

Let's go to configure Atom to automatically lint files and show us messages while coding.

Be sure you have completed successfully the previous sections.

Install the Atom plugin [linter-eslint](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-eslint). You are finished :)
The plugin will detect automatically the `.eslintrc` file in your project and will start linting on the fly the source code showing all the errors and warning.

Comment: You should quote/summarize the relevant text from the link in the event that the link becomes unavailable